Lubuntu no boot device on soft reset
Linux newbie here.
I have recently installed lubuntu v22.04 (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) on a HP t640 ThinClient.
AMD Ryzen R1505G
Radeon Vega 3
4GB Ram
16GB SSD
When i originally bought the machine, it came with IGEL OS pre-installed. I then installed lubuntu from USB stick, replacing the IGEL OS i thought. (I don't want dual boot)
Cold booting the machine works, but whenever i do a reboot, i get the message "Boot device not found. Please install an operating system on your hard disk."
On a cold boot, when i go into the boot menu, ubuntu is listed as an UEFI boot source:

After a reset, it does not list any UEFI boot sources at all.
This is what the KDE Partition Manager looks like:

So i see there is no mount point set for the root partition, is that the problem? Its locked and i don't know how to change it. And why would that configuration work on a cold boot, but not on a reboot?
Thank you.

It's odd that you have what appear to be two different EFI boot partitions related to IGEL. It's also odd that you have any unallocated space. My guess is you did a manual partition and messed it up. I suggest reinstalling and using the "Erase Disk" option.

I have re-installed lubuntu on this machine using the "erase disk" option as you suggested. I get the same problem on a reboot:  "boot device not found".

Don't know if this works, trying to post an screenshot of the partition manager:
https://imgur.com/a/SyjtnTa

I don’t understand why you have unallocated space.  Assuming you did it right, the only likely explanation as to why it didn’t work would be that the installation media is corrupted. Did you verify it?

I'm sure i selected the "erase disk" option. Which tool could i use to check the drive?
There is a hard drive check as part of the HP Bios, but even on a cold boot (which successfully boots) it says no hard disk found when i want to do the hard drive check.

I did another install, this time selecting manual partitioning, trying to not create unallocated space. I created to partitions, one for boot, one for the OS. Still the exact same behavior. The bios does not even recognize the SSD on a reboot.
And it seems there is no way to not create unallocated space as you can see here:
https://imgur.com/a/1eZAOCa
Its different from before. But i only set up two partitions as described, not two and then one for unallocated space as it is now.
